# Extract content of <script> with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

1/ I am trying to extract a part of the script using beautiful soup but it prints Nothing. What's wrong ?

```
URL = "http://www.reuters.com/video/2014/08/30/woman-who-drank-restaurants-tainted-tea?videoId=341712453"
oururl= urllib2.urlopen(URL).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(oururl)

for script in soup("script"):
        script.extract()

list_of_scripts = soup.findAll("script")
print list_of_scripts
```

2/ The goal is to extract the value of the attribute "transcript":

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "VideoObject",
    "video": {
        "@type": "VideoObject",
        "headline": "Woman who drank restaurant&#039;s tainted tea hopes for industry...",
        "caption": "Woman who drank restaurant&#039;s tainted tea hopes for industry...",  
        "transcript": "Jan Harding is speaking out for the first time about the ordeal that changed her life.               SOUNDBITE: JAN HARDING, DRANK TAINTED TEA, SAYING:               \"Immediately my whole mouth was on fire.\"               The Utah woman was critically burned in her mouth and esophagus after taking a sip of sweet tea laced with a toxic cleaning solution at Dickey's BBQ.               SOUNDBITE: JAN HARDING, DRANK TAINTED TEA, SAYING:               \"It was like a fire beyond anything you can imagine. I mean, it was not like drinking hot coffee.\"               Authorities say an employee mistakenly mixed the industrial cleaning solution containing lye into the tea thinking it was sugar.               The Hardings hope the incident will bring changes in the restaurant industry to avoid such dangerous mixups.               SOUNDBITE: JIM HARDING, HUSBAND, SAYING:               \"Bottom line, so no one ever has to go through this again.\"               The district attorney's office is expected to decide in the coming week whether criminal charges will be filed.",
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

`extract` remove tag from the dom. That's why you get empty list.

---

Find `script` with the `type="application/ld+json"` attribute and decode it using `json.loads`. Then, you can access the data like Python data structure. (`dict` for the given data)

for Python 2.x:

```
import json
import urllib2

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = ("http://www.reuters.com/video/2014/08/30/"
        "woman-who-drank-restaurants-tainted-tea?videoId=341712453")
oururl= urllib2.urlopen(URL).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(oururl)

data = json.loads(soup.find('script', type='application/ld+json').text)
print data['video']['transcript']
```

UPDATE: for Python 3.x:

```
import json
import urllib.request

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = ("http://www.reuters.com/video/2014/08/30/"
       "woman-who-drank-restaurants-tainted-tea?videoId=341712453")
oururl= urllib.request.urlopen(URL).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(oururl)

data = json.loads(soup.find('script', type='application/ld+json').text)
print(data['video']['transcript'])
```

Comment: When I try with this link: [link](http://www.reuters.com/article/2014/08/26/ichitan-group-indonesia-green-tea-idUSL3N0QW27F20140826), using this code:
data = soup.findAll('span', id='articleText')
I get an empty content again even if I don't use extract: <span id="articleText">
<span id="midArticle_start"></span>
<span class="focusParagraph"></span></span>

Comment: @laihob, It's different question. Isn't it?  Anyway, try: `print ''.join(soup.find('span', id='articleText').strings)`

Comment: Yeah, The previous question worked well. This time, I want to extract the article in that link which is located inside the <span id="articleText">, I will try what you said now. thx

Comment: Just tried it. Well, actually, `soup.find('span', id='articleText').strings` gives `None` as a result

Comment: That's weird, I have been trying using the same code u wrote, and it gave me an error saying: TypeError
That's the code I tried:
`#!/usr/bin/python`
`import urllib2`
`from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup`
`URL = "http://www.reuters.com/article/2014/08/26/ichitan-group-indonesia-green-tea-idUSL3N0QW27F20140826"`
`Content = urllib2.urlopen(URL).read()`
`soup = BeautifulSoup(Content)`
`soup.find('span',id='articleText').strings`
`print ''.join(soup.find('span',id='articleText').strings)`

Comment: @laihob, It's hard to read the code in the comment. Please post a new question.

Comment: @laihob, Are you using BeautifulSoup 3? Please try it with bs4.

Comment: I just did and it worked now well !! the problem was with BeautifulSoup3 !! thanks

Comment: This works. If you want to examine other scripts with its index (position)

`for i,tag in enumerate(soup.findAll('script')):
    print(i,tag.text)`

If you are using on iPython, you can try `??Tag` or `??Find` to show the implementation behind it in order to find other attributes

Comment: Had to do some modifications for my specific case, but this answer did help me get there most of the way.

Comment: @falsetru Please update code for Python3.

Comment: @Raymond, The question is tagged with `python-2.7` ;)    For Python 3.x, 1. Replace `print` statement with `print(...)` function call.   1. Replace `urllib2.urlopen(..)` with `urllib.request.urlopen(..)` and related import.

Answer (score 80):

From the [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text):

> As of Beautiful Soup version 4.9.0, when lxml or html.parser are in use, the contents of `<script>`, `<style>`, and `<template>` tags are not considered to be ‘text’, since those tags are not part of the human-visible content of the page.

So basically the accepted answer from **falsetru** above is all good, but use `.string` instead of `.text` with newer versions of Beautiful Soup, or you'll be puzzled as I was by `.text` always returning `None` for `<script>` tags.

Comment: Thanks for this answer for the latest version of bs4

Comment: You commented, not answered. btw `urllib2` is also depreciated. Edit the answer above or give a new answer.

Comment: @flywire, I'm confused by your comment, please clarify what you'd like here?

Comment: Click edit on original answer and just change `.text` to `.string`. Add your comments to the question.

Comment: @flywire: Tried to update the answer from @falsetru but update got rejected (there was more to it than that since that answer is in Python2 so other tweaks were necessary including re. urllib2 as you noted). I think having my answer separately as it is works fine though, I don't plan on retrying that update: Key takeaway is needing `.string` for `<script>` and co.

Comment: puzzler here too. thanks for this answer

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for the inspiration. I've been trying for hours how to do it. But let me tell you that since Python3 doesn't work with urllib2 anymore, we must use the requests library instead urllib2. I just drop here the updated version. Enjoy ;)

```
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = input('Enter url:')
html = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text,'html.parser')

data = json.loads(soup.find('script', type='application/ld+json').text)
print(data['articleBody'])
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing update for Python3.