# Web scraping using beautifulSoup and urllib

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am using python 3.6 and I am able to scrape text using BeautifulSoup.I was practicing with Walmart website.I was trying to scrape text from Walmart. Here is my code.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
main_page=urlopen('http://www.walmart.com/ip/Sceptre-32-Class-HD-720P-LED-TV-X322BV-SR/55427159')
soup = BeautifulSoup(main_page,"lxml")
title=soup.select_one("h1.prod-ProductTitle.no-margin.heading-a").get_text()
price=soup.select_one("span.Price-group").get_text()
highLights=soup.select_one("div.ProductPage-short-description-body").get_text()
description=soup.select_one("div.about-desc").get_text()
print(title,"\n",highLights,"\n",description,"\n",price)
```

In above code I am extracting product name,price,high lights and description, but I am not able to extract description(About this item). Instead of description I am getting something else.

Please help me to over come from this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Because there are 2 divs with class="about-desc", since you use select_one only the first div returned but you need the second one. Here's the tweak:

```
description=soup.select("div.about-desc")[1].get_text()
```

**Update:** The site actually blocks urllib's default user agent, so you should mask that.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request
user_agent = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0'}
req = urllib.request.Request(url="http://www.walmart.com/ip/Sceptre-32-Class-HD-720P-LED-TV-X322BV-SR/55427159", headers=user_agent)
main_page = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
soup = BeautifulSoup(main_page,"lxml")
title=soup.select_one("h1.prod-ProductTitle.no-margin.heading-a").get_text()
price=soup.select_one("span.Price-group").get_text()
highLights=soup.select_one("div.ProductPage-short-description-body").get_text()
description=soup.select("div.about-desc")[1].get_text()
print(title,"\n",highLights,"\n",description,"\n",price)
```

Answer (score -1):

There're two option:

- parse `JSON` using `requests` + `beautifulsoup`
- using `requests-html` or `selemium`

If you run this in Chrome console you'll get the following response:

```
test = JSON.parse(document.querySelector("#item").textContent).item.product.buyBox.products[0]
console.log(test)
```

[image]

```py
import json, requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    "User-Agent":
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

response = requests.get('https://www.walmart.com/ip/Wilson-The-Duke-Official-NFL-Game-Football/5192758', headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

# https://stackoverflow.com/a/63151716/15164646
fus = soup.select_one('#item').string
ro = json.loads(fus)
dah = json.dumps(fus, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False)
print(dah)
```

Part of the output:

```json
{
  "item": {
    "ads": {
      "config": {
        "lazy-homepage-expose1": "800",
        "lazy-search-expose1": "800",
        "lazy-browse-expose1": "800",
        "lazy-category-expose1": "200",
        "no-category-marquee2": true,
        "no-deals-skyline1": true,
        "no-homepage-twocolumnhp": true,
        "lazy-item-expose1": "800",
        "lazy-item-marquee2": "1200",
        "lazy-item-rightrail2": "1200",
        "adblockImgSource": "//i5.walmartimages.com/dfw/63fd9f59-8bc2/8fe200ec-4c4d-4ab0-89e5-0662af6f506d/v1/ads.png",
        "displayAdsS2sScript": "//i5.wal.co/dfw/63fd9f59-a579/be6f8cae-248d-40e2-8cad-32d04468ea59/v29/usgm-s2s-midas.js",
        "displayAdsS2sScriptWithPoly": "//i5.wal.co/dfw/63fd9f59-5870/c8ceb4ee-1e68-40ec-a38e-ca0623f075a0/v29/usgm-s2s-midas-poly.js",
        "safeframeUrl": "https://i5.wal.co/dfw/63fd9f59-d6ba/07b8ea82-184c-4ea3-8ac0-5dc1981e40c8/v50/safeframe.html",
        "displayAds": true,
        "exts2s": true,
        "isTwoDayDeliveryTextEnabled": true,
        "ads2s": true,
        "bypassproxy": false,
        "adblockDetectionEnabled": false,
        "marqueeSafeframe": true,
        "exposeSafeframe": true,
        "skylineSafeframe": true,
        "leftrailSafeframe": true,
        "rightrailSafeframe": true,
        "cloud": "scus-prod-a29"
      }
}
# much more down below...
```

The following code is using `requests-html`. One way to grab the "about this item" description is to use `XPath`.

Code (tested on several listings):

```py
from requests_html import HTMLSession

session = HTMLSession()
response = session.get('https://www.walmart.com/ip/Sceptre-32-Class-720P-HD-LED-TV-X322BV-SR/55427159')

# first=True means that it will grab the first occurrence and skip everything else
title = response.html.find('.prod-productTitle-buyBox', first=True).text
price = response.html.find('.prod-PriceHero', first=True).text.split('$')[1]
description = response.html.xpath('//*[@id="about-product-section"]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/p[1]/text()', first=True)
key_features = response.html.xpath('//*[@id="about-product-section"]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/ul[1]', first=True).text

print(title)
print(price)
print(description)
print(key_features)
```

Output:

```
Sceptre 32" Class 720P HD LED TV X322BV-SR
129.00
Escape into a world of splendid color and clarity with the X322BV-SR. 
Clear QAM tuner is included to make cable connection as easy as possible, without an antenna. 
HDMI input delivers the unbeatable combination of high-definition video and clear audio. 
A USB port comes in handy when you want to flip through all of your stored pictures and tune into your stored music. 
More possibilities: with HDMI, VGA, Component and Composite inputs, we offer a convenient balance between the old and new to suit your diverse preferences. 
With the ability to connect your computer, laptop, monitor, or TV to all your favorite variety of input options, VGA inputs deliver superb analog video.

Screen Size (Diag.) 31.5"
Backlight Type LED
Resolution 720p
Effective Refresh Rate 60Hz
Smart Functionality no
Aspect Ratio 16 9
Dynamic Contrast Ratio 5,000 1
Viewable Angle (H/V) 178 degrees/178 degrees
Number of Colors 16.7 M
OSD Language English, Spanish, French
Speakers/Power Output 10W x 2
Surround Sound Mode
```

---

Alternatively, you can use third-party [Walmart Product API](https://serpapi.com/walmart-product-api) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free trial of 5,000 searches. A completely free trial is currently under development.

Code to integrate:

```py
from serpapi import GoogleSearch

params = {
  "api_key": "YOUR_API_KEY",
  "engine": "walmart_product",
  "product_id": "55427159"
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

title = results['product_result']['title']
price = results['product_result']['price_map']['price']
key_features = results['product_result']['detailed_description_html']
print(title)
print(price)
print(key_features)
```

Output:

```
Sceptre 32" Class 720P HD LED TV X322BV-SR
129
<b>Sceptre 32" Class 720p HD LED TV X322BV-SR</b><br /><b>Key Features </b></p><ul><li>Screen Size (Diag.) 31.5"</li><li>Backlight Type LED</li><li>Resolution 720p</li><li>Effective Refresh Rate 60Hz</li><li>Smart Functionality no</li><li>Aspect Ratio 16 9</li><li>Dynamic Contrast Ratio 5,000 1</li><li>Viewable Angle (H/V) 178 degrees/178 degrees</li><li>Number of Colors 16.7 M</li><li>OSD Language English, Spanish, French</li><li>Speakers/Power Output 10W x 2</li><li>Surround Sound Mode</li></ul><b>Connectivity </b><ul><li>Component/Composite Video 1</li><li>HDMI 2</li><li>Headphone 1</li><li>Optical Digital Audio 1</li><li>RCA Audio L+R 1</li><li>RF (Coaxial) 1</li><li>USB 2.0 1</li><li>Assembled Product Dims 28.78 x 18.39 x 7.95 Inches<br /></li></ul><b>What's In The Box </b><ul><li>Remote Control</li></ul><b>Wall-mountable </b><ul><li>Mount Pattern 100mm x 100mm</li><li>Screw Size M4</li><li>Screw Length 6mm</li></ul><b>Support and Warranty </b><ul><li>1-year limited labor and parts</li></ul><br /><br />Flat Screen TV stand sold separately. See all <b> TV stands.</b><br /><br />Flat Screen TV mount sold separately. See all <b> TV mounts. </b><br /><br />TV audio equipment sold separately. See all <b> Home Theater Systems. </b><br /><br />HDMI cables sold separately. See all <b> HDMI Cables.</b><br /><br />Accessories sold separately. See all <b> Accessories.<br /></b><br /><br /><b>ENERGY STAR<sup></sup></b><br />Products that are ENERGY STAR-qualified prevent greenhouse gas emissions by meeting strict energy efficiency guidelines set by the U.S. Environmental Protection Agency and the U.S. Department of Energy. The ENERGY STAR name and marks are registered marks owned by the U.S. government, as part of their energy efficiency and environmental activities.
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.