# How to cull dictionaries that is in between HTML Tags as an element?

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, csv, web-scraping, urllib2

How can I cull the `{juicy_dictionary}` from the scrapped HTML source where its tagged like

```
<div data-qa-id="doctor_card" class="u-cushion u-white-fill u-normal-text o-card o-card--separated c-list-card" data-reactid=*><script type="application/ld+json" data-reactid=*>{juicy_dictionary}</script>
```

Example: This page view-source:https://www.practo.com/delhi/doctors.
I am unable to think of ways of doing it. my scrapped file is saved as CSV where I saved all html source as-it-is in a CSV file.

Comment: With `bs4`: `soup.find('script').text`

Comment: Thanks Adam. Exactly what I required. Here is another implementation of it. :)  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26192727/extract-content-of-script-with-beautifulsoup