# To use Regex or not, to grab json value from a HTML

Tags: python, json, regex

So I have been getting some mixed answers here. Either to run with regex or not.

what I am trying to do is that I am trying to grab a specific value (The json of spConfig) in the html which is:

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
        {
            "#product_addtocart_form": {
                "configurable": {
                    "spConfig": {"attributes":{"93":{"id":"93","code":"color","label":"Color","options":[{"id":"8243","label":"Helloworld","products":["97460","97459"]}],"position":"0"},"148":{"id":"148","code":"codish","label":"Codish","options":[{"id":"4707","label":"12.5","products":[]},{"id":"2724","label":"13","products":[]},{"id":"4708","label":"13.5","products":[]}],"position":"1"}},"template":"EUR <%- data.price %>","optionPrices":{"97459":{"oldPrice":{"amount":121},"basePrice":{"amount":121},"finalPrice":{"amount":121},"tierPrices":[]}},"prices":{"oldPrice":{"amount":"121"},"basePrice":{"amount":"121"},"finalPrice":{"amount":"121"}},"productId":"97468","chooseText":"Choose an Option...","images":[],"index":[]},
                    "gallerySwitchStrategy": "replace"
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
```

and here is the problem. When scraping the HTML, there is multiply `<script type="text/x-magento-init">` but only one `spConfig` and I have two question here.

1. Should I grab the value spConfig using Regex to later use json.loads(spConfigValue) or not? If not then what method should I use to scrape the json value?
2. If I am supposed to regex. I have been trying to do grab it using `\"spConfig\"\: (.*?)` however it is not scraping the json value for me. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using BeautifulSoup? Or is this dynamically loaded javascript that you're getting from Splash or from scraping headless with Selenium? If using soup: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26192727/extract-content-of-script-with-beautifulsoup

Comment: @mgrollins Sorry for not mention it! I am using BeautifulSoup `bs4 = soup(requests.text, 'html.parser')` where I later on use `for values in bs4.find_all('script', {'type': 'text/x-magento-init'}):`

Comment: OK, great! Check that answer, it looks like you can convert the `values` to json through loads: `data = json.loads(values.text)` and then test if `spConfig` is a key in data and then use the attributes.

Comment: @mgrollins Yupp I did thaht :) However now I am having issue with grabbing the correct .items() value but that problem wouldn't fit here since this is something else :)

Comment: I would load it all with json and then use Try/Catch to access the right script tag, I'll type something up as an answer if there's not a new one already.

Comment: Ooh! Nevermind, looks like @QHarr has you covered with a nice, very specific answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, with bs4 4.7.1 + :contains is your friend. You say there is only a single match for that so you can do the following:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import json

html= '''<html>
 <head>
  <script type="text/x-magento-init">
        {
            "#product_addtocart_form": {
                "configurable": {
                    "spConfig": {"attributes":{"93":{"id":"93","code":"color","label":"Color","options":[{"id":"8243","label":"Helloworld","products":["97460","97459"]}],"position":"0"},"148":{"id":"148","code":"codish","label":"Codish","options":[{"id":"4707","label":"12.5","products":[]},{"id":"2724","label":"13","products":[]},{"id":"4708","label":"13.5","products":[]}],"position":"1"}},"template":"EUR <%- data.price %>","optionPrices":{"97459":{"oldPrice":{"amount":121},"basePrice":{"amount":121},"finalPrice":{"amount":121},"tierPrices":[]}},"prices":{"oldPrice":{"amount":"121"},"basePrice":{"amount":"121"},"finalPrice":{"amount":"121"}},"productId":"97468","chooseText":"Choose an Option...","images":[],"index":[]},
                    "gallerySwitchStrategy": "replace"
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
 </head>
 <body></body>
</html>'''
soup = bs(html, 'html.parser')
data = json.loads(soup.select_one('script:contains(spConfig)').text)
```

Config is then:

```
data['#product_addtocart_form']['configurable']['spConfig']
```

with keys:

[image]

Comment: Amazing! Exactly what I was looking for here! Appreciate it and this seemed to be alot easier than I actually thought it would be!

Answer (score 1):

No, don't ever use regex for HTML. Use HTML-parsers like `BeautifulSoup` instead!

Comment: Right! Hmm the question is how would I in that case be able to grab the value if there is multiply values of `<script type="text/x-magento-init">` any suggestions because theh problem is I am out of ideas haha.

Answer (score 0):

So basically for json use json parser right. ?  And for yaml use yamel parser  so in HTML do use HTML parser 
See some example and also like that will make you life to shine

from html.parser import HTMLParser

```
class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        print("Encountered a start tag:", tag)

   def handle_endtag(self, tag):
      print("Encountered an end tag :", tag)

  def handle_data(self, data):
      print("Encountered some data  :", data)

 parser = MyHTMLParser()
parser.feed('<html><head><title>Test</title></head>'
        '<body><h1>Parse me!</h1></body></html>')
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html