# Extract JSON in between <script> tags with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, json, parsing, beautifulsoup

Apologies for the newbie question but I've been stuck on this for a while.

Here's the situation:

- I'm trying to extract a job description from a React.js website
- I manage to get the following using Beautiful Soup with Python

```
    bs_object = [<script type="application/ld+json">{
        "key-a": "value-a",
          "key-b": "value-b",
          "key-c": {
            "another-key": "another-value",
            "yet-another-key": "yet-another-value",
            }
          }
        }</script>]
```

My problem?

I can't figure out how to access the values included in the dictionary.

- I've managed to get rid of the [ ] with a simple bs_object[0]
- Tried calling bs_object[0]["key-b"] => returns a KeyError
- Tried calling bs_object[0].key-b => returns None

Also tried this: [Extract content of <Script with BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26192727/extract-content-of-script-with-beautifulsoup)

Bottom line is, I'm stuck.

Can you help out?

Answer (score 2):

The link you have provided is 5 years old, and it's not python 3, here is python 3 working version.

```
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get("https://coronameter.cc")

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

data = json.loads(soup.find('script', type='application/ld+json').text)

print(data["@type"])
```

Comment: For newer versions of BeautifulSoup you'll likely need `.script` instead of `.text` in the `json.loads` line above, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/63151716/9624052