# beautiful soup get text from script tag aws

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to crawl the imdb website. I'am extracting info from the "application/ld+json" file, and using beautifulsoup to parse the page. When I run the script in my local machine it works fine, but I am tryng to deploy it on aws, and the beautifulsoup get_text method does not work.

I even made some tests in the aws instance withe the python console. When I ask for the whole tag it works:

```
html.find(attrs={'type':"application/ld+json"})
<script type="application/ld+json">{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "TVSeries",
  "url": "/title/tt5753856/"....}
```

But when I try to extrat only de text within the tag it returns a empty string:

```
html.find(attrs={'type':"application/ld+json"}).get_text()
''
```

Does anyone has any idea how can I solve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extract content of <script> with BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26192727/extract-content-of-script-with-beautifulsoup)

Comment: Still does not work. The thing is that this script works fine in my computer, but in AWS (and I also tried google cloud) dont work..

Comment: A lot of sites employ anti-crawler tactics, maybe the site you are crawling blocks all traffic from Azure?

Comment: Try printing / storing the html to see if @Iain Shelvington is right. Check status code too.

Your code works fine both on my Digital Ocean instance and local machines so I agree that this has to do with something else than BeautifulSoup.

Comment: Btw why screenscrape imdb that has an api? https://developer.imdb.com