# Need help getting tr values when scraping

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have the following code

```
# Import libraries
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.ipma.pt/pt/otempo/obs.superficie/table-top-stations-all.jsp'

page = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')
# Get the content for tab_Co id 
temp_table = soup.find('table', id='tab_Co')
# Create Headers
headers = []
for i in temp_table.find_all('th'):
 title = i.text
 headers.append(title)
# Create DataFrame with the headers as columns 
mydata = pd.DataFrame(columns = headers)

# This is where the script goes wrong
# Create loop that retrieves information and appends it to the DataFrame
for j in table1.find_all('tr')[1:]:
 row_data = j.find_all('td')
 row = [i.text for i in row_data]
 length = len(mydata)
 mydata.loc[length] = row
```

What am I doing wrong? The final purpose is to have a dataframe where I can extract the top 4 values for each column

```
'Temperatura Max (ºC)',
 'Temperatura Min (ºC)',
 'Prec. acumulada (mm)',
 'Rajada máxima (km/h)',
 'Humidade Max (%)',
 'Humidade Min (%)',
 'Pressão atm. (hPa)']
```

and then use those to generate a daily image.
**Any ideas? Thank you in advance!**

*Disclaimer: This is for a non-for-profit project and no commercial use will be made of the solution.*

Comment: The table is dynamically constructed with JavaScript. bs4 can't *run* JS so that's the reason you're not getting anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this worked, based on this solution by [Falsovsky on GitHub](https://gist.github.com/falsovsky/aa5423db4c71ff3dbfeeff48b9102ed5)

```
# Import libraries 
import requests
import pandas as pd
import regex
# Define target URL 
url = 'https://www.ipma.pt/pt/otempo/obs.superficie/table-top-stations-all.jsp'

# Get URL information 
page = requests.get(url)

# After inspecting the page apply a regex search 
search = re.search('var observations = (.*?);',page.text,re.DOTALL);

# Create dict by loading the json information
json_data = json.loads(search.group(1))

# Create Dataframe from json result 
df1 = pd.concat({k: pd.DataFrame(v).T for k, v in json_data.items()}, axis=0)
```

Answer (score -1):

From the source `view-source:https://www.ipma.pt/pt/otempo/obs.superficie/table-top-stations-all.jsp`, it is clear that the data is in the `th` attributes so try scraping with `row_data = j.find_all('th')`

Comment: That only gives me the headers, which I already have. What I'm trying to get is the information within ````<tr role="row" class="odd"><td class="sorting_1">Aguiar da Beira (CIM)</td><td class="">17.3</td><td>6.2</td><td></td><td></td><td>100</td><td>44</td><td></td></tr>````

Comment: @JorgeGomes The data values itself is in the `script` which you will have to scrape in it's entirety which you will get as a string and then you'll have to convert it to json and finally using the respective keys, you can get the data

Comment: any idea how to do that?

Comment: Extract the JSON from the source and parse it to rebuild the table you see in the browser. That's basically what happens behind the scenes with JS.

Comment: And how do I extract the JSON?

Comment: @JorgeGomes I think this might help [Extract content of <script> with BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26192727/extract-content-of-script-with-beautifulsoup)